# Improve wireless performance

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, signal

I have a [Trust Speedshare Turbo Pro](http://www.trust.com/products/product.aspx?artnr=13643) router, which is running on channel 6. I found that the wireless signal (and network performance) dramatically drops from my PDA (I can barely attach to the network, even if I set the PDA's energy settings to **maximum wireless performance**) when I even exit my room, and I don't have shielded walls or something like that. I can't even stream a SD video from my desktop (connected via LAN) to my laptop using WiFi, while via LAN it works fine.

I read that changing router's channel **could** improve performance due to interference reducing. I found that **almost all** wireless networks around here run on channels 6 and 11. I tried to go to my router's settings page to change channel, but I found that the combo box only allows me to select 6!! I'm not sure, but I may have been able in the past to change channel, though not to all of the available channels. A few minutes ago I tried a firmware upgrade, but it didn't solve my problem.

## My question is

1. Is it possible that my router is someway **locked** to its channel? I bought it on my own, I didn't receive it from my ISP
2. Apart from boosting the antenna power to the maximum (which, by the way, increases the EM radiation my and my family's bodies absorb 24/7 and is *little* more environment-unfriendly), do you have any tips on getting high quality transmission up to 5 metres from the antenna?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the channel if you are using the router in Turbo mode. ALSO the range is reduced. Is this your problem?

From the manual:

> Turbo When enabled, 2 channels are used in parallel for double throughput. Limitations: Only works in combination with Turbo Pro series wireless products. Can be used only on channel 6. Range will be shorter.

Comment: Ha, you found the same thing I did. Who would have thought to read the manual...

Comment: Oh, yea... Looks like I was so *attracted* by this fancy word "Turbo" and possibly made a mess. This definitely solves my **ranging** problem